# Why do we say "blood" when speaking about kinship

Tags: idioms, kinship-terms

The usage of the term *blood* when speaking about relatives, like *blood relatives*, *blood right*, *bloodline* is not obvious at all, when I start to think about it. I wonder what are the origins of it, namely did people use to think that blood is something that is shared between relatives? To my surprise I have not found any comprehensive treatment of this question on Internet, hence I'm asking it here.

Since this useage is something that is met not only in English, but also e.g. in Latin and many of its derivative languages, I guess it may fit some other community better (perhaps https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) so feel free to transfer my question where it will better belong. Thank you.

Comment: As you say, not really an English language question - but, yes, people used to believe that   heredity was somehow transmitted in the blood.

Comment: The blood type of parents directly affects that of their offspring.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: I'm pretty sure, the usage of this term precedes the discovery of blood types

Comment: @KateBunting: indeed, my question is - why would they think about blood in particular as a transmitter of kinship

Comment: Blue bloods were understood to inherit hemophilia, for example.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: that sounds better to me than blood types. Perhaps indeed, one made observation about relatives sharing blood color, and deduced that it may be an indicator of kinship. Still, would be nice to have a source for that

Comment: Blue blood is also a synonym of "noble birth". (In French it even means "royal blood"!)

Comment: @fev same in Russian, though there it might have come from French during its influential period around 19th century

Comment: Синняя кровь? Yes, had forgotten about that!

Comment: @fev it would be more correct to say "голубая" (Russian has a special word for *light blue*). The phrase you've said would not be understood, in best case it will be thought of as the vein blood (often drawn as dark blue), but not as the royal one. Anyways, that's a bit of an offtopic

Comment: What are we talking about? The heredity of children **IS** contained in their blood, and in every other cell in their bodies. Blood is what we see when looking inside a body, so it's the first idea that comes to mind. Plus, blood is generally not good news when you see it; you wanna keep it inside.

Comment: @JohnLawler It's true that heredity is contained in the blood, but ironically red blood cells are the one type of cell in the human body which don't show it, in the sense that they lack both nucleus and mitochondria.

Comment: @JohnLawler blood is definitely not the first thing that we see in the body or inside the body. I'd say the flesh is

Comment: In Arabic, the body part used to describe kinship is "womb" (رَّحِمُ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The origins are in human nature. As you yourself note, *blood* is used in most languages to describe kinship. Biologically, we are born of the flesh of our parents. Their blood is said to flow in our veins and modern discoveries of genetics and DNA prove that.

[Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/kinship-3026370) has an article about kinship and enumerates its types, of which the first is of course:

> ***Consanguineal*** (of the same blood): This kinship is ***based on blood—or birth***: the relationship between parents and children as well as siblings, says the Sociology Group. This is the most basic and universal type of kinship. Also known as a primary kinship, it involves people who are directly related.

Blood is what it is, and flesh is too. Indeed, in times of old ***flesh*** and ***seed*** were also used to describe lineage:

> ...concerning his Son Jesus Christ our Lord, which was made ***of the seed of*** David ***according to the flesh***. (Rom. 1:3 KJV)

Blood is described as a means of ***transmitting filiation and identity*** in this article:

> During the past several decades, historians of Rome have been considering a series of questions raised by anthropologists about the symbolic meanings of bodily humors, especially blood. It is becoming evident that in ancient Rome, ***blood***—***the fluid substance linked with filiation and the transmission of identity***—was the object of a set of perceptions much more complex than used to be thought.
>  (Moreau, Philippe. “[The Bilineal Transmission of Blood in Ancient Rome.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt9qcvpd)” *[Blood and Kinship: Matter for Metaphor from Ancient Rome to the Present](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Blood_and_Kinship/LVdFAAAAQBAJ?hl=en)*, edited by Christopher H. Johnson et al., 1st ed., Berghahn Books, 2013, pp. 40–60)

Here is an *[interesting thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/f5snlv/how_did_blood_become_associated_with/)* which claims that the origin of the use of ***blood*** to describe kinship lies in Aristotle. This may be the answer you are looking for:

> We talk about bloodlines and blood relatives because of Aristotle. The short version is that Aristotle believed that semen was a highly purified form of blood, and that menstrual blood was similar but less purified, and the blending of the two resulted in the conception of a child. Since much of Western philosophical and scientific thought centered on Aristotle for many centuries, some of his terminology has stuck long after science has moved past the ideas behind it.

Comment: Interesting: if by *seed* they imply male reproductive cells, that would be somewhat earlier than discovery of them causing pregnancy. Also, in case of JC that definitely should not have been the reason according to the Bible. Anyways, thanks for question, but that does not really explain why would blood be used so often, rather than flesh.

Comment: Have a look at the last link. It has many quotations on the subject.  Another quote says: "The reference to blood as a symbolic support for the link between certain categories of kin is currently of common usage, at least in some European languages, and historians generally employ it without further reflection."

Comment: That's definitely a very nice finding! Unfortunately, I don't have an access to the book or its articles.

Comment: Me neither, but at least it gives you an idea of the dimensions of the problem: anthropological, sociological, theological, biological, philosophical, etc. etc. It gives you directions for your research.

Comment: Definitely. I've upvoted and will accept if nothing more comprehensive appears as an answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have added the link from Google Books for "Blood and Kinship". You can search inside the book, and even read large passages from it.

Comment: Very nice of yours, I was thinking of that. Another alternative I've considered is sending an email to one of the editors.

Comment: @Ilya — Knowledge of the relationship between semen and pregnancy seems evident from the Old Testament injunction against spilling one’s seed on the ground. Whether this refers to coitus interruptus or masturbation, it is reasonable to suppose it arose from society’s need for procreation for survival. And to suggest sheep farmers were unaware of this connection…

Comment: @David not sure I understood the last sentence. And not sure I should try to

Comment: @Ilya — You raised the point, but SE EL&U is hardly the place to discuss it. Hence my unsuccessful attempt to condense an argument.

Comment: This is an overstatement: "Their blood is said to flow in our veins and modern discoveries of genetics and DNA prove that." You can't even necessarily receive a blood transfusion from a given parent, since they can easily be of a different blood type. Obviously, your DNA is a mixture of your parents' DNA and isn't identical to either's DNA. Each protein in your blood can be identical to a protein in one of your parent's blood, but this is true of all body tissues, not just the blood. There is no scientific reason to prefer blood over any other tissue.

Comment: @WaterMolecule seems to have quite some knowledge about liquids :)

Comment: @David just sounded as a borderline indecent joke

Comment: @Ilya — Certainly not. And I am a biologist.  Although the biblical injunction is often taken to be against masturbation,  it makes more sense if it is against a form of birth control, with the motivation of ensuring the propagation of the tribe. This, and the reference to seed, suggest a knowledge of the role of semen in fertilization.

Answer (score 3):

"Blood" (the fluid matrix, not the specific English word) has historically been related to life and vitality. From the Bible:

"For the life of the flesh is in the blood: and I have given it to you upon the altar to make an atonement for your souls: for it is the blood that maketh an atonement for the soul."
Leviticus 17:11 KJV

"Only be sure not to eat the blood, for the blood is the life, and you shall not eat the life with the flesh."
Deuteronomy 12:23

I use the Bible as an example here, but blood is considered a sacred fluid across many cultures. It's abundantly clear, even in ancient times, that losing blood directly and immediately relates to loss of life.

"Line" is a word with many definitions. One of which means:
"Family; Lineage"
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/line)

"Blood" (the English word this time) also has many definitions. One of which is:
"Human stock or lineage. Broadly: Life."
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blood

Furthermore, your specific blood type is entirely dependent on the blood type of your parents. If both parents are A, it will be impossible for you to have type B or type AB blood. So there is a certain "passing on" of blood down the family line.

Comment: Thanks, though it does not answer the origins clearly. Definitely, not the latter point you've mentioned

Comment: That's fair, I missed you asking specifically about origins so apologies